# Enlarge Newsfeed images on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, my-site, event-handlers, my-profile, newsfeed

I am a bit stumped why I have not found much information on this topic or why no one is asking the question. Maybe it is just not possible.

My question being: **Are you able to enlarge Newsfeed images in SharePoint 2013(for example clicking on them in the feed)?**

I understand they get uploaded as a certain size thus enlarging them wouldn't make sense.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange!!

It is **not possible out of the box**, just so that you know!

But, your problem was so interesting that I thought of spending couple of hours just to develop a small customization :)

So this is how my solution works:

1. The default size of images posted on Newsfeed time-line is 300x300px
2. I developed a custom feature that injects JavaScript and CSS on the
   fly, and with the help of jQuery, you can Zoom-in and Zoom-out the
   Newsfeed image :)
3. **Remember** I set the starter height and width of image to be 150x150px (zoom-out size). When you click the image it will animate
   from 150px to 300px, kinda of animating zoom-in affect

See the pictorial demo below:

**The normal Newsfeed image with 150px:**

[image]

**The Newsfeed image with Zoom effects 300px**
[image]

Here is the link to [complete source code](http://falakmahmood.blogspot.se/2013/11/zoom-in-sharepoint-newsfeed-images.html). Please download and rate the project and feel free to improve it :)

Happy SharePointing!

Comment: Firslty thank you tihs solution but ı dont understand how to import this .sln folder.
Where is the import this folder .I m working Sharepoint Designer and Internet Exp in Sharepoint Site

Comment: Link dead......

Comment: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=zoomsharepointnewsfeed

Comment: Solution didn't do anything for me.